# ASP.NET MVC 5 tutorial error: The type or namespace name could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm working through an ASP.NET MVC 5 tutorial on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VAtVv1Q7ufM). I'm really enjoying it. However, I'm stuck on what seems to be a strange error. Strange meaning I think I have everything typed in as in the tutorial, but VS2013 is flagging me, and I can't figure out what might be wrong. Defining the math variable as a Course seems fine. However, then it doesn't like math.

[image]

Models/Course.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MyfirstProject.Models
{
    public class Course
    {
        int CourseID { get; set; }
        string CourseName { get; set; }
        int TotalCredits { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controllers/XyzController.cs

```
using MyfirstProject.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyfirstProject.Controllers
{
    public class XyzController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Xyz
        public ActionResult Abc()
        {
            Course math = new Course();
            .....
            .....
```

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong with your code just try cleaning the solution and rebuild it.

Comment: Note: you have created all the property as private in the Course POCO model. I think this would have been intended to be public.

Comment: I tried cleaning and rebuilding. Then closing and reopening. What is private? I'm not familiar with the term POCO. Maybe that's why I don't understand.

Comment: @abalter, because you have not used the `public` modifier - `public int CourseID { get; set; }` - you cannot access the properties.

Comment: Try actually writing the code as you think it should work (ignoring the Intellisense) and compiling it.  Then show us the error from the compiler.  That is usually more trustworthy then the error from the Intellisense.  Like others have said, you can't access the properties because they are not public, but the error still doesn't make sense, and you still should be getting intellisense for members inherited from "object".

Comment: @LeonidTsybert making the class variables public did fix the problem. I hear what you are saying. I tried just compiling it, and I got the same error. Actually, I copied and pasted the error from the compiler output. But I'm pretty much a noob, so maybe there's a place to look for more detailed compiler output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean and rebuild the solution as  Jenish Rabadiya mentioned in comment.

**Update**

Make the attributes public in the following class

```
 public class Course
{
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public int TotalCredits { get; set; }
}
```